# change windows search results default thumbnails size?

Tags: windows-10, search

Windows 10 **search results** always display my images in middle sized thumbnails.

And usual folder settings to set default looks are greyed out as *inaccessible*.

Is there no way to change the default thumb size for win 10 search results?

Comment: The default view for SearchResults depends on the *Foldertype* of the search source. Most display in `Content` mode, with the exception of the `Pictures` *FolderType*, which defaults to Large icons. What type of folder are you searciing and what is your desired results mode?

Comment: I'm searching picture type folder and I want EXTRA large icons (the same size as I have my picture folder in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set Search results for Pictures to Extra Large icons, do the following:

1. Copy and paste the following into **Notepad** or another text editor, then save it to your Desktop with any name but with a `.reg` extension:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}]
   @="Pictures.SearchResults" 
   "Mode"=dword:00000001
   "IconSize"=dword:00000100
   "LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
   ```
2. *With all **Explorer** windows closeed*, clear any saved Search Results views by copying and pasiing the following code into a **PowerShell** console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute:

   ```
   (gci 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -s | ? PSChildName -eq '{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}') | Remove-Item -Force
   ```

   Close the console window after running the code.
3. On the Desktop, right-click the `.reg` file you createed earlier, select `Merge`, and aceept the confirmation dialogs.
4. Sign out and log back in or restart. (Doesn't always seem necessary -- but when in doubt..)
5. Open a *Pictures* folder and perform a test search.

As an alternative to creating and merging a `.reg` file, you can perform the registry mod with **PowerShell** as well:

```
$KeyPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d}'
[PSCustomObject]@{
    '(Default)'     = 'Pictures.SearchResults'
    LogicalViewMode = 3
    Mode            = 1
    IconSize        = 256
} | Set-ItemProperty -Path (mkdir $KeyPath -Force).PSPath
```

If you opt for this, copy and run this block *after* running the earlier code to clear existing views.

Comment: Indeed, sadly it seems regedit voodoo magic is the only way to do such a trivial task...

I also found a program to do that regedit for you - WinSetView

Comment: Yes, I know about the program, the author picked my brain when writing the program... :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [**WinSetView**](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView) makes it easy to set up your default folder view preferences, including defaults for search results. @KeithMiller is acknowledged in the manual for "for documenting the FolderTypes approach to setting default views". @Owyn provided excellent feedback that led to several improvements to the app.